# Skip "Inf" values when plotting data with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I know that with pgfplots you can skip "unbounded coords", but latex only accepts "nan", "inf" and "-inf" (and actually different capitalization for "nan" also) as the unbounded coords.

My data contains a lot of "Inf" and "-Inf" values, for which pgfplots gives an error. See the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump]
\addplot coordinates {
(0,0) (10,50) (20,Inf) (30,200)
(40,inf) (50,600) (60,NaN) (80,1000)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to tell latex to treat "Inf" as "inf"? I guess I could write a script to convert all my "Inf"s to "inf"s, but it would be much cleaner and easier do it through latex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define `Inf` to be an alias for `inf` by setting `declare function={Inf=inf;}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={Inf=inf;}]
\begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump]
\addplot coordinates {
(0,0) (10,50) (20,Inf) (30,200)
(40,inf) (50,600) (60,NaN) (80,1000)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]