# How to jump some data points in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I use the Mathematica to export the data points and use the pgfplots to plot the figure. The data file contains some points whose y value is Indeterminate. A mwe can be given by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
    x y
    1 2
    2 4
    3 Indeterminate
    4 7
}\mydata
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot table {\mydata};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to jump these points. How can I do that?

Comment: Try skip rows: skip rows between index = {<begin>} {<end>}. So use... \pgfplotstabletypeset[ skip rows between index={0}{2}, skip rows between index={4}{5} ]{mydata.csv} to skip row 1,2,4,5.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thanks for your comments :-). The data file contains many many points and I want to make the pgfplots skip those points automatically.

Comment: Contain this points nan values? Or could you show a small image of this data. Maybe related https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243980/124842

Comment: The related question you provide is what I want. But I also found that  pgfplotstable doesn't works with this solution. For example `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={Indeterminate=inf;}]
\begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump]
\addplot coordinates {
(0,0) (10,50) (20,Indeterminate) (30,200)
(40,Indeterminate) (50,600) (60,Indeterminate) (80,1000)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}` works

Comment: But `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.11}
\pgfplotstableread{
(0,0) (10,50) (20,Indeterminate) (30,200)
(40,Indeterminate) (50,600) (60,Indeterminate) (80,1000)
}{\mydata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={Indeterminate=inf;}]
\begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump]
\addplot table {\mydata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}` doesn't work.

Comment: Can you change the Mathematica output so that you get `nan` instead of `Indeterminate`?

Answer (score 2):

You can save the table to a file, indicating that you want `string replace={Indeterminate}{inf}` (it doesn't work when reading the table, as far as I can see) and then reload the table from the saved file.

In other words, adding

```
\pgfplotstablesave[string replace={Indeterminate}{inf}]{\mydata}{mydata.dat}
\pgfplotstableread{mydata.dat}\mydata
```

between `\pgfplotstableread` and the `tikzpicture` seems to do what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
    x y
    1 2
    2 4
    3 Indeterminate
    4 7
}\mydata
\pgfplotstablesave[string replace={Indeterminate}{inf}]{\mydata}{mydata.dat}
\pgfplotstableread{mydata.dat}\mydata
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot table {\mydata};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]